# method not applicable for the arguments, but not sure why

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have the following method which takes a list of classes as a parameter:

```
public List<Interface> getInterfacesOfTypes(List<Class<? extends InternalRadio>> types) {
    List<Interface> interfaces = new ArrayList<Interface>();

    for(Interface iface : _nodes)
        if(types.contains(iface._type))
            interfaces.add(iface);

    return interfaces;
}
```

What I want to do is create a wrapper for it where only a single class is specified, which calls the above method with a list of only that one class:

```
public List<Interface> getInterfacesOfType(Class<? extends InternalRadio> type) {       
    return getInterfacesOfTypes(Arrays.asList(type));
}
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
The method getInterfacesOfTypes(List<Class<? extends InternalRadio>>) in the type InterfaceConnectivityGraph is not applicable for the arguments (List<Class<capture#3-of ? extends InternalRadio>>)
```

I can't figure out why this is or what the `capture #3-of` even means.  I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I understand your problem but, why don't you just create an `ArrayList`, add `type` into that and pass it to your `getInterfacesOfTypes(List<Class<? extends InternalRadio>)` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Change the interface to the following:

```
public List<Interface> getInterfacesOfTypes(List<? extends Class<? extends InternalRadio>> types)
```

To be quite honest, I cannot really explain why. Broadening the range of allowed generic collections (by adding '? extends') just makes it easier for the compiler to see this is valid...

**Aside**

- Instead of `Arrays.asList(type)` I would write `Collections.singletonList(type)`.
- Prefixing class members with '_' is uncommon in Java
- I think `Interface` is not a great name as 'interface' is also a Java concept (and it seems `Interface` is not such an interface :) )
- I'd probably use an 'getType()' function on Interface instead of directly referring to its '_type' field - this makes for easier refactoring later.
- You can probably accept any `Collection` rather than requiring a `List`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of you object types:

```
public List<Interface> getInterfacesOfType(final Class<? extends InternalRadio> type)
    {
        final List list = Arrays.asList(type);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<Class<? extends Interface>> adapters = list;

        return getInterfacesOfTypes(adapters);
    }
```